# Creating folders with for loop in windows batch

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I want to create a set of folders, for example named folder1, folder2, folder3,..., folder40 using a windows batch file. I could do this using the command `call md folderN` 40 times for N in (1,40), but i was wondering if i could use a for loop to do this?

I have tried using `FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,40) DO call md folder%%I` to do this but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This does also work here in XP:

```
FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,40) DO call md folder%%I
```

.. or on the command line:

```
FOR /L %I IN (1,1,40) DO call md folder%I
```

... but this doesn't work:

```
FOR /L %I IN (1,1,40) DO call :md folder%I
```

Answer (score 1):

`MD` is an internal Windows command. That means that it should be directly invoked, not CALLed.

So, you just need

```
 for /L %%a in (1,1,40) do md folder%%a
```

Comment: I couldn't get what you wrote to work for me but i used:

`do i = 1 to 40
                md folder%i
enddo`

which worked fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you are not in windows cmd shell, I assumed you were. But probably in powershell instead.